# Acceder al atributo id de un elemento seleccionado por su clase en js

Tags: javascript, html5

mi problema es ele siguiente...quiero acceder al atributo ID de un elemento pero seleccionandolo por su clase, osea..

este es el elemento.

```
<div class="capaClickeable" id="1"></div>
```

lo selecciona con getElementsByClassName por que son varios elementos

```
var id = document.getElementsByClassName('capaClickeable');
```

como es obvio que cada div tiene la `class="capaClickeable"` y un `id="1" id="2"`...etc.

quiero acceder a esos ids y guardarlos en un array o algo por el estilo.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes obtener un array con las id de tus elementos con clase capaClickeable así:

```js
const ids = [...document.querySelectorAll('.capaClickeable')].map(el => el.id);
console.log(ids)
```

```html
<div id="1" class="capaClickeable"></div>
<div id="2" class="capaClickeable"></div>
<div id="3" class="capaClickeable"></div>
```

Comment: Madre mia, jajaja gracias a ambos estan muy buenas sus respuestas

Comment: Wow ! no conocía este método tan corto, genial !

Answer (score 3):

Lo haces de la siguiente manera:

Método manual

```
var elemento = document.getElementsByClassName('capaClickeable'); 
var id = elemento[0].getAttribute('id');
```

Método automático

```
var elemento = document.getElementsByClassName('capaClickeable'); 
var cantidad = elemento.length;
var array_id = Array();

for(var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++){
    var id = elemento[i].getAttribute('id');

    array_id.push(id);
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Lo intente y me dice que elementogetAttribute, no es una funcion

Comment: Entonces hazlo así: `elemento[0].getAttribute('id');`

Comment: OMG :) :) :)  graciaaaas funcionooo

Comment: Para seguir capturando los `id` de los otros elementos debes editar el índice `[0]` por el índice de cada elemento, o para hacerlo de manera automática podrías ejecutar un ciclo `for` con la cantidad de elementos capturados, te editaré la respuesta con esta última opción para que veas.

Comment: @OdannysDeLaCruz si te sirvió como solución, maraca la respuesta como aceptada por favor.